# Generator on Python3+Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I try to make a number generator(so how  by lotto - numbers from-to, and need to get some quantity from(for example:6 numbers from 1-50)).
This is the code:`

```
from tkinter import *

def printer(event):
    import random
    s = random.sample(range("a", "b"),"c")
    print(s)
    return

root = Tk()

s = StringVar()

lab = Label(root, text="Minimum", font="Arial 10")
ent = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3,text="a")
lab.pack()
ent.pack()

lab = Label(root, text="Maximum", font="Arial 10")
ent = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3,text="b")
lab.pack()
ent.pack()

lab = Label(root, text="Quantity", font="Arial 10")
ent = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3,text="c")
lab.pack()
ent.pack()


but = Button(root, text="GO!",
             width=20,height=5,
             bg="green",fg="yellow")
but.bind("<Button-1>", printer)
but.pack()

lab = Label(root, text="Result", font="Arial 10")
ent = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3,text=(printer))
lab.pack()
ent.pack()

root.mainloop()`
```

But, when I click "GO" button, I got:

```
"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1490, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/juri/lotto_gui.py", line 5, in printer
    s = random.sample(range("a", "b"),"c")
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly"
```

What I made wrong? Please help me!

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this line `random.sample(range("a", "b"),"c")`?

Comment: This will be for example random.sample(range(1, 50), 6) - I get 6 random numbers from 1 to 50; number 1("a") need to go in window "minimum", 50("b") - in "maximum" and 6 ("c") - "Quantity"

Comment: So a,b and c are some integer variables?

Comment: Yes, it is so, and GUI is  looks like this [link](http://firepic.org/?v=2015-03-27_pgzoq47ihi7i.png)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i think I understand no. I changed your code to make it work:

```
from tkinter import *


def printer(event):
    global s # use global StringVar to show the results
    import random

    r_sample = random.sample(range(a.get(), b.get()), c.get())

    # set the s variable with the random sample
    s.set(",".join(map(str,r_sample)))
    return

root = Tk()



s = StringVar()

# IntVars added here
a = IntVar()
b = IntVar()
c = IntVar()


lab = Label(root, text="Minimum", font="Arial 10")
ent = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3, textvariable=a)
lab.pack()
ent.pack()

lab = Label(root, text="Maximum", font="Arial 10")
ent = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3, textvariable=b)
lab.pack()
ent.pack()

lab = Label(root, text="Quantity", font="Arial 10")
ent = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3, textvariable=c)
lab.pack()
ent.pack()


but = Button(root, text="GO!",
             width=20,height=5,
             bg="green",fg="yellow")
but.bind("<Button-1>", printer)
but.pack()

lab = Label(root, text="Result", font="Arial 10")
ent = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3, textvariable=s)
lab.pack()
ent.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Basicly, I made a,b,c variables as `IntVar`. Also fixed your `printer` so that it uses the three variables, and updates `s` variable.

[image]

Comment: Marcin, Thank You, that  exactly what I want!